# Removing comma from an object property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object with one of the pairs having a value which has a comma in it. I want to remove this comma for all such values in the object and return the modified object. The object is as follows -

```
var obj = [
            {
            id: 1,
            Product1: "Table",
            Phone1: "9878987",
            Price:"21,000"},
        {
            id: 2,
            Product1: "Chair",
            Phone1: "9092345",
            Price:"23,000"},
        {
            id: 3,
            Product1: "Cupboard",
            Phone1: "9092345",
            Price:"90,000"}    
        ];

alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I want to remove comma in Price value(e.g- 23,000 ==> 23000). How can this be done?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array and [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove comma from `Price` property

Code:

```js
const obj = [{id: 1,Product1: "Table",Phone1: "9878987",Price:"21,000"},{id: 2,Product1: "Chair",Phone1: "9092345",Price:"23,000"},{id: 3,Product1: "Cupboard",Phone1: "9092345",Price:"90,000"}]

const result = obj.map(({ Price, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  Price: Price.replace(/,/, '')
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Before replacing, how to check that value is having comma or not in same loop ? Let suppose comma is available in phone and price fields both

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using regex without using loop.

```
var obj= ... //your array
obj= JSON.stringify(obj);
obj= obj.replace(/(?=,(?!"))(,(?!{))/g,"");
obj= JSON.parse(obj) //you get you object without , in between your values
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
var obj = [
            {
            id: 1,
            Product1: "Table",
            Phone1: "9878987",
            Price:"21,000"},
        {
            id: 2,
            Product1: "Chair",
            Phone1: "9092345",
            Price:"23,000"},
        {
            id: 3,
            Product1: "Cupboard",
            Phone1: "9092345",
            Price:"90,000"}    
        ];

for (var i in obj) {
  var Price = obj[i].Price.replace(',','');
  obj[i].Price = Price;
}        

  console.log(obj);
```

**Working Fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/pn3u8pdh/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RegEx to replace. This should work for any number of commas in the string.

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  Product1: "Table",
  Phone1: "9878987",
  Price: "1,21,000"
}, {
  id: 2,
  Product1: "Chair",
  Phone1: "9092345",
  Price: "23,000"
}, {
  id: 3,
  Product1: "Cupboard",
  Phone1: "9092345",
  Price: "90,000"
}];

var modifiedArray = obj.map(function(currentObj) {
  var replaceRegex = new RegExp(",", "g");
  currentObj.Price = currentObj.Price.replace(replaceRegex, "");
  return currentObj;
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML =
  JSON.stringify(modifiedArray);
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```